# Arcade Expression for Label Halo Color

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro, expression, arcade

I am trying to label Census Block Groups and Tract ID for the block group feature layer. I would like to label them using different color halos. Is there an arcade expression that will allow me to change the color of the halos for each label in a feature?

So far, I have been able to change the color of the text for the labels but not the color of the halo.

```
"<CLR red = '0' green = '197' blue = '255'>" + 
'Tract ' + 
"<BSE>" + $feature.TRACT + "</BSE>" +
"</CLR>" + 

TextFormatting.NewLine + 

"<CLR red = '223' green = '115' blue = '255'>" + 
"BG - " + $feature.BLKGRP + 
"</CLR>"
```

From the image below, I basically want to invert the colors of the halo and the text.

[image: Block Group and Tract Labels with different colors]

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong but I do not believe Halo  is a property you can alter with HTML tags as described in the [help file](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/text/text-formatting-tags.htm).

What you can do is create classes of labels, each with their particular halo characteristics. You add a new class under the dropdown from here:

[image: Add a new label class]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have tried that and it does work but how may I get the 2 classes of labels to align with each other and center one under the other? I would like the tract on top and BG on bottom.